# Visual Studio 2012 saying 'Unable to edit' when including remote CSS file

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012

I have included the CDN of the bootstrap CSS in my project. Everything works absolutely fine, except when I type

```
<div class="
```

Then Visual Studio pops up an error saying:

> Unable to edit 
>   'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'. 
>   here`The style sheet must be part of the current project and the project must be a Web Site or Web Application project

I can hit OK to dismiss these errors, and then everything works fine as well - it reads the CSS classes and populates Intellisense and works correctly when I build. But why is Visual Studio trying to edit the remote CSS file? How can I tell it not to?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: interestingly i only started seeing this after windows 10 upgrade. Ayrab's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and a little search brought me to the following page:

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1586914.aspx?Unable+to+edit+CSS+file+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1586914.aspx?Unable%20to%20edit%20CSS%20file%20)

In a nutshell:  Add a fake parameter to the end of your CDN URL to get rid of your errors. This also makes intellisense work correctly.

Example:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css?parameter=1" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Bit of a misnomer there "intelli"-sense. FYI this method doesn't work too well with VS2015 and I'm still looking...